# How to recive the output from cUrl

Tags: php, magento, curl

i've been tasked converting a payment gateway for magento from asp to php, the asp one is outdated for an old site and what's required is a new one, looking at all of the asp code i can easily do it but there is one thing that gets me.

Magento uses this `Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl` to send xml to the payment gateway and while i understand how the .asp file get the xml data (using `Request.InputStream`) i can't seem to duplicate that in a php file. this is as close as i can get

```
function Page_Load()
{
    $cUrl = curl_init();

    $dump = curl_exec($cUrl);

    $file = fopen("Gateway.txt","w");
    echo fwrite($file,var_export($dump,true));
    fclose($file);

    var_dump($dump);
}

Page_Load();
```

i changed the payment gateway URL in magento backend to my php file and went though the checkout, it creates the .txt file but all it contains is false

so how do i receive the output from magento in my Page_Load function, at the moment i'm just outputting it to a file just to confirm that i am getting a response

UPDATE: i have chnaged the code to this

```
function Page_Load()
{
    $cUrl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($cUrl,CURLOPT_URL,"http://my.site.local/Current-Build/gateway/Gateway.php");
    curl_setopt($cUrl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    $dump = curl_exec($cUrl);

    if(!$dump)
    {
        $dump = curl_error($cUrl);
    }

    $file = fopen("Gateway.txt","a");
    echo fwrite($file,var_export($dump,true));
    fclose($file);

    curl_close($cUrl);

    var_dump($dump);
}

Page_Load();
```

the site is on a wamp served that's been put online so anyone on in my development team can access it and it is also the same path that is specified in magento in the payment methods for the payment gateway url which was set to the old aspx file

when i then go though the checkout, while magento gives me the normal error cause it's not getting a response my output file isn't even being created, when i try to go back to magento it just sits there loading and i have to restart WAMP Server a couple of times cause it sits on the orange logo for ages

Comment: Is [`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) what you're looking for?

Comment: Instead of `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()` you can use `file_put_contents()` with `FILE_APPEND` flag.

Comment: @Jack didn't make a difference, as i have explained in my edit the output file isn't even being created, i delete the file every time so i know that it's outputted rather than getting confused with data that was already there